# Selecting Elements from a listbox with Selenium in Java

Tags: java, selenium, listbox, webdriver

So i have the following HTML Code of a listbox here:

```
<div role="listbox" aria-expanded="false" class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectEl docssharedWizSelectPaperselectRoot freebirdFormviewerViewItemsSelectSelect freebirdThemedSelectDarkerDisabled" jscontroller="YwHGTd" jsaction="click:cOuCgd(LgbsSe); keydown:I481le; keypress:Kr2w4b; mousedown:UX7yZ(LgbsSe),npT2md(preventDefault=true); mouseup:lbsD7e(LgbsSe); mouseleave:JywGue; touchstart:p6p2H(LgbsSe); touchmove:FwuNnf; touchend:yfqBxc(LgbsSe|preventMouseEvents=true|preventDefault=true); touchcancel:JMtRjd(LgbsSe); focus:AHmuwe; blur:O22p3e;b5SvAb:TvD9Pc;" jsshadow="" jsname="W85ice" aria-describedby="i.desc.709120473 i.err.709120473" aria-labelledby="i73">
    <div jsname="LgbsSe" role="presentation">
        <div class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectOptionList" jsname="d9BH4c" role="presentation">
            <div class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectOption freebirdThemedSelectOptionDarkerDisabled exportOption isSelected isPlaceholder" jsname="wQNmvb" jsaction="" data-value="" aria-selected="true" role="option" tabindex="0">
                <div class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectRipple exportInk" jsname="ksKsZd"></div>
                <content class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectContent exportContent">Auswählen</content>
            </div>
            <div class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectOptionSeparator" role="presentation"></div>
            <div class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectOption freebirdThemedSelectOptionDarkerDisabled exportOption" jsname="wQNmvb" jsaction="" data-value="140 cm" aria-selected="false" role="option" tabindex="-1">
                <div class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectRipple exportInk" jsname="ksKsZd"></div>
                <content class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectContent exportContent">140 cm</content>
            </div>
            <div class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectOption freebirdThemedSelectOptionDarkerDisabled exportOption" jsname="wQNmvb" jsaction="" data-value="141 cm" aria-selected="false" role="option" tabindex="-1">
                <div class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectRipple exportInk" jsname="ksKsZd"></div>
                <content class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectContent exportContent">141 cm</content>
            </div>
            <div class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectOption freebirdThemedSelectOptionDarkerDisabled exportOption" jsname="wQNmvb" jsaction="" data-value="142 cm" aria-selected="false" role="option" tabindex="-1">
                <div class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectRipple exportInk" jsname="ksKsZd"></div>
                <content class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectContent exportContent">142 cm</content>
            </div>
            <div class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectOption freebirdThemedSelectOptionDarkerDisabled exportOption" jsname="wQNmvb" jsaction="" data-value="143 cm" aria-selected="false" role="option" tabindex="-1">
                <div class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectRipple exportInk" jsname="ksKsZd"></div>
                <content class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectContent exportContent">143 cm</content>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectDropDown exportDropDown" role="presentation"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="exportSelectPopup quantumWizMenuPaperselectPopup" jsaction="click:dPTK6c(wQNmvb); mousedown:uYU8jb(wQNmvb); mouseup:LVEdXd(wQNmvb); mouseover:nfXz1e(wQNmvb); touchstart:Rh2fre(wQNmvb); touchmove:hvFWtf(wQNmvb); touchend:MkF9r(wQNmvb|preventMouseEvents=true)" role="presentation" jsname="V68bde" style="display:none;"></div>
</div>
```

I am writing an program which has to select an element of this listbox (like "140 cm", "141 cm" you see in the code etc...) automatically in java. I tried to access the listbox with the following code:

```
WebElement checkBox = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[aria-labelledby*=i73]"));
CheckBox.click();
```

It worked, but i am failing to select an element. I tried it with the "Select"-Command:

```
Select listbox = new Select(checkBox);
listbox.selectByVisibleText("140 cm");
```

But it did not work. Do you have any suggestions? I am thankfully for everyone trying me to help! Thank you, guys. :)

Comment: The selenium select class will not work here as this is not a conventional dropdown. You will need to find the specific div option with the '140...' text and then send a click to it.

Comment: So you mean i have to send a click to this div: `<div class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectOption freebirdThemedSelectOptionDarkerDisabled exportOption" jsname="wQNmvb" jsaction="" data-value="140 cm" aria-selected="false" role="option" tabindex="-1">
                <div class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectRipple exportInk" jsname="ksKsZd"></div>
                <content class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectContent exportContent">140 cm</content>` Because there is no other div option with '140...' text in the whole html code...

Comment: Yes... After you have opened the dropdown (which u have done successfully) find this div using the 'data-value' attribute and then click on this element.

Comment: First of all: thank you for your help; I tried it with `WebElement boxElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[data-value*='140']"));
        boxElement.click(); ` After I have opened the dropdown. But i get the exception that this element is not visible, although it clearly is on the webbrowser :/

Comment: Use an expicit wait on the visibiity or clickabiity of this div...

Comment: Already tried it. Still does not work. Same exception.

Answer (score 0):

After the wait for clickability, try

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
Duration aDuration = Duration.ofSeconds(1);
action.moveToElement(boxElement).pause(aDuration).click(boxElement).build().perform();
```

The rationale is that sometimes Javascript has to execute when the element has focus before the click, for it to work.

While moveToElement is supposed to scroll I find that it often does not.  So I use an explicit scroll before the action.

```
/**
 * 
 * @param webDriver
 * @param elementToScrollIntoView
 * @param blockOption - If true, the top of the element will be aligned to the top of the visible area of the scrollable ancestor.
 *                      If false, the bottom of the element will be aligned to the bottom of the visible area of the scrollable ancestor
 */
public void explicitScrollIntoView(WebDriver webDriver, WebElement elementToScrollIntoView, boolean blockOption) {
    final String scriptStr = "arguments[0].scrollIntoView(" + blockOption + ");";
    ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript(scriptStr, elementToScrollIntoView);

    sleepResponsibly(500);

}

public void sleepResponsibly(int timeMillisecond){
    try{
        Thread.sleep(timeMillisecond);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); 
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```

The pause and sleep are to give the Javascript time to finish.